# Middleware being executed even after respnse being sent

Tags: node.js, express

I was wrting very basic express code

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use('/willgo', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('In a middleware');
    next();
})

app.use('/notgo', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('In another middleware');
    res.send('<h1> Inn intermediate </h1>');
    res.end();
})

app.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('In final middleware');
    res.send('<h1> Inn final </h1>');
})

// const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
// server.listen(2001);

app.listen(3002);
```

On `localhost:3002/notgo` the console is

```
In another middleware
In final middleware
```

It shows that the last middleware executed, even though I have already sent the request.

Is this the deafult behavior or I am missing something because res.send() is supposed to finish the processing.

Comment: Why not use `get(...)` ?

Comment: Also noticed something, the `res.end()` is redundant, as `res.send()` will anyway send response and terminate the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop,

`res.end();` will finish the response. But does this code need to be middleware or plain endpoints?

Then you should use app.get();

The console output 'In final middleware' is probably because the browser wants to load a favicon.ico from the root, which will call app.use('/', .... )

If you would do a curl / invoke web request from the cli you would see that there is only one console output.

on windows 10/11: `(iwr http://localhost:3002/notgo).content`

Comment: Now that I see it, there is GET to `/favicon.ico` in Networks. Also, the `res.end()` was me experimenting to apparantly force it to exit.

Comment: Here you can find more info on when to use middleware: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html